# Set height constraint for UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, autolayout

I'm fairly new to iOS development and am having a hard time sizing a UITextView to it's content. I've found several examples of calculating a strings render size and/or updating the frame size of a textview, however I can't seem to get those to work.

When I add a UITextView to my view it adds a Height constraint which I think is locking it to a specific height. How can I work around it, update the constraint via code, and/or get my UITextView to resize vertically to show my content?

Answer (score 8):

You can create an outlet to the vertical size constraint, and then adjust the `.constant` property of the constraint to amend the height of your text view.

Comment: This is by far the easiest way to adjust a constraint manually. Well done.

Comment: Works very well for me too. You should mark @jrturton's post as the answer.

Comment: wow! Im so pissed I didn't think of this.  So much wasted time.

Comment: Had a bit of trouble getting this to work, but it turned out I was missing a couple of constraints. Once the whole view was happily constrained, worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A UITextView inherits from UIScrollView.  As part of it's logic, it changes the height of its contentSize property to allow the user to scroll vertically to any portion of the TextView's content.

I would recommend using the ContentSize property of your UITextView to figure out how "tall" your content really is.  You can then set the frame of your UITextView accordingly.

OR:  You could figure out the size of your text using the right method from the NSString+UIKitAdditions category.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want autolayout then disable it in the xib file.

If you want to change the contraint and it's value this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2) will help you to deal with autolayout.